# Why is the Nobel Literature Prize committee primarily staffed by Swedish nationals?

Tags: awards, nobel-prize

So far as I understand(I might be wrong), the 5 or so people that form the committee that decides who should get the Nobel Prize for Literature are primarily Swedish Nationals. [Here's a list of the current commuter members](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/prize_awarder/committee.html).

Now given that the Nobel for Literature is an international prize that is given to people from many different cultures and languages, shouldn't the committee that decides who should get the prize rather be composed of many people from different cultures who speak different languages, so as to make the proceedings more fair?

Comment: Interesting question (assuming the premise is correct, of course).

Comment: The Nobel Committee for Literature 2017 - Members:
Per Wästberg (Chairman),
Anders Olsson,
Kristina Lugn,
Horace Engdahl,
Sara Danius,
Katarina Frostenson.
Seems pretty Swedish to me, I think. Also not 15, so I might have to edit my question.

Comment: If you have a source for their nationality, can you please [edit] it into the question? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the point of the question. If an individual leaves a bequest for a prize and that prize to be awarded by a named and pre-existing national institution... why is it anybody's business but that of the Swedish Academy and the Nobel Foundation to say how it 'should' be done?

Comment: The Nobel prize for Literature is the biggest prize in Literature. It's a international prize that can supposedly be given to any writer from any culture. To have just Swedish nationals, presumably speaking mostly European languages decide who gets the immense prestige of the Nobel Prize seems just slightly biased.

Comment: @GenRincewind It is an international prize in that it *can* be awarded to writers from any country, i.e. non-Swedes are not excluded. But it is a prize awarded by a private foundation, with the assistance of a National Institution, from funds bequeathed by an individual. There is surely no obligation on it beyond the terms of Alfred Nobel's will?

Comment: They have no obligation to be multicultural, but it would be advantageous, seeing as it is hard to judge a book in a language you cannot read. Anyway, regardless of the original origins of the award, it is incredibly prestigious, and because its bestowment conveys so much, it should be reasonably fair, and a buncha Swedish people judging books they cannot read, which is most of the world, doesn't strike me as very fair to most of the world.

Comment: @GenRincewind You cannot 'disregard the original origins' though; without the Nobel Foundation, created to administer the bequest, which is the source of the prize fund, there *is* no prize. Their prize, they get to run it how they like. They are apparently aiming for a more global distribution. But why don't you spend some time on their website yourself? https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/facts/literature/

Comment: Yes, but I protest the notion that simply because the Nobel Foundation is Swedish and they control the prize, that they should dictate everything about the prize, including that the deciding committee should be primarily composed of Swedish Nationals, especially if there's no clause in Nobel's will that states it should be so, and especially since they're trying to be more global.

Comment: I don't believe there was any International Academy of the Arts at the time that Nobel made his will. Nobel was Swedish, so the Swedish Academy was a perfectly reasonable choice to administer it. Except for the Peace Prize, the administration of the other Nobel Prizes was given to the appropriate Swedish academies, and they have generally done a good job of selecting the winners.

Comment: @GenRincewind As far as I can see you are unhappy that Swedes give prizes to non-Swedes without also giving non-Swedes the running of their prize. Are you really saying that they should in some way not be allowed to run their own thing their own way, just because they don't limit awards to their countrymen? Because that's where protesting them 'dictating' ends up.

Comment: @GenRincewind In addition to Spagirl's answer, the "immense prestige of the Nobel Prize" comes from the way it as been awarded and the country which administers it. It got this prestige from the works (and the funds) of swedes awarding Nobel prizes to whom they found more fit. Given that prestige, they doesn't seem to have failed much.

Comment: In business, they refer to this as the "Golden Rule", specifically *"he who has the gold, makes the rules."*  The selection committee is perennially criticized, but the charter is the charter.

Answer (score 11):

Alfred Nobel's will states that

> [Priset] [...] för litteratur [utdelas] af Akademien i Stockholm[...]

or, in English

> The award for Literature shall be awarded by the Academy in Stockholm

All the awards are granted by academies based in Stockholm, except for the peace prize, which is awarded by a five-member committee chosen by the Parliament of Norway.

The Academy has then elected to organize the work in the following manner:

- A large group of people, including Academy members, professors, and former winners, are able to suggest people for consideration
- A four or five-member sub-committee, elected for three years, does the heavy lifting of registering, investigating and recommending winners. They can ask for expert opinions of outsiders, and ask for translations if not enough such are available. They reduce all the suggestions to a short-list of about twenty.
- Then the entire Academy discuss the list, and it is reduced further to five.
- Over the summer, the members read such authors that they need to get further acquainted with.
- Early autumn, they vote on the winner.

As for the nationality of the Academy, I have not been able to find the statutes, but [this](https://www.svd.se/andra-akademiens-stadgar-nu) LTE makes it clear that only people of Swedish nationality are eligible (and thus not, e.g. Swedish-speaking Finns). They could, I guess, involve more non-members in the preparatory work, but I think it would be hard to wiggle away from the wording of the will, even if it is clearly the work of Nobel's own hand, not a lawyer. In the end, it is the Swedish Academy, and no other body, that is responsible for awarding the prize.

Also, remember that there was actually an uproar about the fact that the awards should be granted "without regards to nationality" when the contents of the will first became known. Even so, while the prizes have always been of a very substantial sum, it was in no way clear from the start that they would take on the significance they have today.

### Sources

- [Nobel's will](http://www.nobelprize.org/alfred_nobel/will/testamente.html)
- [How the Swedish academy organizes the awarding of the prize.](http://www.svenskaakademien.se/nobelpriset/hur-nobelpristagare-i-litteratur-utses)

Comment: So is there a clause in the will of Alfred Nobel that forbid non-Swedish nationals from joining the Nobel committee? I can't read Swedish :-{

Comment: I have quoted the entirety of what it says about who awards the prize in literature. It says nothing about any committee, just that the Academy is responsible for determining who shall receive the prize.

Comment: Ok. So it is a possibility? Possibly?

Comment: @GenRincewind The Nobel Committee is formed of members of the Swedish Academy. So the rules of that Institution apply. As andejon points out, they have translations and other resources. The judgement is about a body of work, it's a literature prize rather than a book prize. Specifically "the person who shall have produced in the field of literature the most outstanding work in an ideal direction".

Comment: @GenRincewind Not as I read it 'The Academy is composed of 18 members whose tenure is for life. Known as "De Aderton" (The Eighteen), current members of the Academy include distinguished Swedish writers, linguists, literary scholars, historians and a prominent jurist. Its working body is the Nobel Committee, elected from among its members for a three-year term.' https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/prize_awarder/index.html

Comment: But translations can be bad, and sometimes you need context to truly appreciate a book,and sometimes the language itself is what makes a book great.  I mean, Bomsok Babelaas is a great Afrikaans song, but if translated it sounds horrible. So you know, you have that whole factor. Plus: Sweden seems to me here in South Africa to be a relatively homogenous society, and as such most people there probably hold similar beliefs, which could bias their selection.

Comment: Ah k. Well, it just seems a bit off. I mean, they've rejected really good English writers like Cormac McCarthy or Irvine Walsh recently in favour of other writers like Swetlana Alexijewitsch, who I'm sure is a great writer, but I've never heard of her.

Comment: But my opinion is really subjective, and prone to error.

Comment: @GenRincewind You don't know who they've rejected because they don't announce who has been nominated and considered. nominations are secret for 50 years. English is the single most represented language in the Nobel Literature winners work (28), Swedish (7), Norwegian (3).